# SELECT query that uses a stored procedure to get the value for one of the columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure that calculates a special value for a given record based on the information contained within that record and some information from other tables.  I'd like to write a query that returns a result table containing each record's regular information, with the addition of each record's calculated value in a new column.  For example, I want something like this:

```
SELECT
   [id]     as Name,
   [shape]  as Shape,
   [color]  as Color,
   EXEC FindCode
       @id = [id]
       @shape = [shape]
       @color = [color] 
   as Code
FROM Shapes
```

With the equivalent of the above 'pseudo' code, I'd expect to get back a result set like this:

```
Name |  Shape  | Color | Code
-----+---------+-------+-----
AB   |  Circle | Blue  | 4276
BC   |  Square | Red   | 9825
CD   |  Rect   | Gray  | 3723
```

Where the Name, Shape, and Color, were already contained in the table as id, shape, and color, but the 'Code' was calculated using the stored procedure.  What's the best way to go about doing this in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: You might want to consider a table-valued function instead of a stored procedure. You can't execute a procedure in the middle of a query like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few examples of what your query might look like using some of the suggestions in this thread.

**1. `CROSS APPLY`ing a scalar-valued user-defined function**:

```
SELECT
     s.[id]     as Name
    ,s.[shape]  as Shape
    ,s.[color]  as Color
    ,c.[code]   as Code
FROM 
    [Shapes] s
CROSS APPLY
    fnFunctionThatCalculatesCodeAsAScalarValue(s.[id], s.[shape], s.[color]) c
```

**2. Changing your table definition to have a computed column:**

```
CREATE TABLE Shapes AS
(
    [id] int NOT NULL,
    [shape] varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    [color] varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    [code] AS fnFunctionThatCalculatesCodeAsAScalarValue ([id], [shape],[color])
)
```

**3. `JOIN`ing a table-valued user-defined function:**

```
SELECT
     s.[id]     as Name
    ,s.[shape]  as Shape
    ,s.[color]  as Color
    ,c.[code]   as Code
FROM 
    [Shapes] s
JOIN
    fnFunctionThatCalculatesCodesAsATable() c
    ON
    s.[id] = c.[id]
    AND
    s.[shape] = c.[shape]
    AND
    s.[color] = c.[color]
```

Or **4.** you could just **pre-fill a different table will all of the possible color codes** (if feasible).

The use of the scalar-value functions as-is in examples 1 and 2 will perform the worst, especially if it has to go after other tables, because it will execute once per row.

You can improve the performance of the computed column example by tacking on the `PERSISTED` keyword after the column definition. **This is probably how *I* would do it**. The persisted values will be calculated once upon insert, auto-updated  when a row updates, but pulled from its persisted location for a select statement.

Comment: Option 2 ended up working very well for my purposes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the algorithm for computing the code is totally based on (dependant) on only the other columns in the same row, then yr best option is to add a computed Column to the table

```
Alter Table MyTable Add Column
   Code as [Enter expression here that calculates the code]
```

e.g.,

```
  Alter Table MyTable Add Column
   Code as Case id 
           When 'AB' Then Case Shape
                             When 'Circle' Then 4176
                             When 'Square' Then 4177
                             When 'Rect'   Then 4178 End
           When 'BC Then  Case Shape
                             When 'Circle' Then 9825
                             When 'Square' Then 9826
                             When 'Rect'   Then 9827 End

           End
```

if this algorithm is dependant on data from other rows, or from other tables, then you need to use a User defined function [UDF].  If possible make it a correlated [InLine Table generating UDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), not a scalar UDF.

Comment: Interesting... will this auto-update when any of the other values are updated?

Comment: The algorithm refers to another table to compute the 'code', so perhaps this approach won't work.

Comment: @Dalal: All the more reason to change your procedure to a table-valued function. In it, you'd populate and return a table variable with all of the possible color value combinations calculated with enough other information to join to your `Shapes` table.

Comment: Yes computed columns are not persisted.. The value is re-computed every time you access the column.   But if the value is dependant on data in another row or another table, then the computed column approach will not work.  The OP will need to use a UDF (a Table-Valued, inline UDF is the best approach)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function that does the same thing as your procedure and then use CROSS APPLY in a query.

Comment: Joining a table-valued function would probably be faster.

Comment: @Rikalous, Hmm... could I create this function on the fly inside the query?  Could you perhaps provide some code that works with my example, substituting the function code with 'function code goes here' or something.  I'm new to SQL, and that would be very helpful.